# Kubernetes NFS server is taking 100% cpu

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, nfs, google-kubernetes-engine

When i create the RC [as given](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/nfs/nfs-server-rc.yaml) in the [nfs tutorial of kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/examples/nfs/README.html) to create the nfs server,
 it uses 100% cpu of a [n1-standard-1 node from GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types):

[image]

Pod logs returns nothing wrong:

```
> kubectl logs nfs-server-*****
Serving /exports
NFS started
```

**Is that normal that nfs consume so much cpu?**

Comment: Answered  there by Ya5e:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22529) in the NFS image you were using.